# Animate animals running accross the screen in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a few thousand JPEGs of different animals. I want to show them moving from the left end of the screen to the right in a web browser. At any point of time there may be a few animals or a few hundred on the screen. How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Add a relevant code snippet of what you've already tried so we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use an already animated looped gif of an animal walking. Then you can just change the position of the gif with JS.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("animal");
      var pos = 0;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 75);
      function frame() {
          if (pos >= 100) {
              pos = -10;
          } else {
              pos=pos+0.25;
              elem.style.left = pos + '%';
          }
      }
```